# When i add this code in workbook received an error

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code which is create a data validation for a range but whenever i add this code in the workbook.
Received this error `"we found a problem with some content"` while opening the workbook but when i remove this from workbook then it works fine.

and when i click on save the updated data in workbook it gives the option to select a folder to save the file.

[image]

Can someone please look into this that what is the issue with the code.

```
Dim list1               As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim validationFormula   As String

    Set list1 = Sheet3.Range("A1:A100")

    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In list1
        If Not IsEmpty(myCell) Then
            validationFormula = validationFormula & myCell.Value2 & ","
        End If
    Next

    validationFormula = validationFormula & Chr(160)

    With Sheet1.Range("C4:C2000").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=validationFormula
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
end with
```

Comment: Is the permissions set to open macros?  Save as excel workbook with macros.  In your VBA code ensure there is no function AutoOpen - there may be some code there that is crashing.

Comment: No. Saved its is working fine without macros and also works fine without updated macro in question. Wherever i update above macro in sheets or Module it gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

```
   Dim list1 As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim validationFormula As String

    Set list1 = Sheet3.Range("A1:A100")
    validationFormula = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.index(list1, 0, 1)), ",")

    With Sheet1.Range("C4:C2000").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=validationFormula
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
   End With
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Learning: Glad I could help! But please, take care: I used your code which did not used `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end. Meaning that after running the code your application does not have events enabled, anymore. I add the line now, looking again to the code...

Comment: I got your point @FaneDuru Thank you for making it clear.

Answer (score 0):

May be the length of Formula1 exceeds 255 chars, but "Formula1 The first part of the data validation equation. **Value must not exceed 255 characters.**" (from MS docs Validation.Add method (Excel))

This code works without errors:

```
Sub ver()
    Dim list1 As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim validationFormula   As String

    Set list1 = sheet1.Range("A1:A100")

    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In list1
        If Not IsEmpty(myCell) Then
            validationFormula = validationFormula & myCell.Value2 & ","
        End If
    Next

    validationFormula = Left(validationFormula, 255)
    If Right(validationFormula, 1) = "," Then validationFormula = Left(validationFormula, Len(validationFormula) - 1)

    With sheet1.Range("C4:C2000").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=validationFormula
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: There can be an alternative of this code @Алексей Р